# Matrix multiplication identity proof

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, inverse, matrix-calculus

How can I prove that $(PQ + I_N)^{-1}P = P(QP + I_M)^{-1}$ knowing that we have two matrix $P_{N \times M}$ and $Q_{M \times N}$.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: What are the conditions on $P$ and $Q$? For $P = I_N$  und $Q = -I_N$ neither side of the equation makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both $PQ + I_N$ and $QP + I_M$ are invertible just multiply from the left with $(PQ + I_N)$ and from the right with $(QP + I_M)$ to obtain the equivalent statement
$$
 P(QP+I_M) = (PQ + I_N)P,
$$
which is true.